# Cordova automatically sync data between several IOS devices using iCloud

Tags: ios, cordova, backup, storage, icloud

I have built an universal hybrid app for IOS devices using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). 
In this app, some data (like score, level progression, settings, preferences, etc) are saved locally using the JavaScript object [LocalStorage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/fr/latest/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html). By this way, when the user quit the app and open it later, everything is like before (as in almost all games :)

What I'm trying to do is to automatic sync this LocalObject (containing all data) with the other IOS devices of the user without forcing him to be connected to Game Center or any other account (except iCloud of course).

*Example: user starts to play on iPhone then later, at home, he wants to continue on his iPad.*

So I read the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/) and I understood I have to set the BackupWebStorage value to "cloud" in the config.xml file to store the data in the cloud then get it automatically from other devices...

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"/>
</platform>
```

After that step, I published my app through the TestFlight and I installed it both on my iPhone and iPad... But unfortunately, it doesn't work... The LocalObject doesn't sync automatically via iCloud.

I did some research on the web about this question and I found nothing clear. I found tones of examples for syncing data between an app and a server (which I know how to do) but nothing about my question...

Could you advise me some technics? May be a demo link? An examples?

I'm pretty sure what I want to do is possible because I have some app installed on my IOS devices working as I explained. For example, when I play with the famous [Alto's Adventure](http://altosadventure.com/), If I switch between my IOS devices during the game, all my progression is immediately and automatically sync between my devices. However, I'm not connected to the Game Center or any other account...

So? How does this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to sync data between iOS devices connected to a same *iCloud* account in a Cordova project. Let see how it works:

#### 1 - Cordova config.xml

In your config.xml file, you ave to set the preference parameter [BackupWebStorage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html) to right value. Choose "cloud":

```
<platform name="ios">
     <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"/>
</platform>
```

#### 2 - Xcode capabilities settings

Open your **/platforms/ios/myProjectName.xcodeproj** file in Xcode. In the **capabilities** tab, you have to switch on the iCloud parameter. Then you can choose the way you want to sync data between Apple devices.

- Key-Value storage
- iCloud Documents
- CloudKit

In my case, I just need to sync datas as key-value storage such as {"playerID":"123456"}.

[image: Xcode Capabilities tab - iCloud key-value Storage]

#### 3 - Add icloudkv plugin to sync key-value datas

Then you have to add a plugin to your Cordova project to be able to sync datas. I used the [cordova-plugin-icloudkv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-icloudkv) which works well for my needs. You can add it using CLI (Terminal on Mac OSX):

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-icloudkv
```

Once is done, you can start adding JavaScript code to your project. Right after the device.ready() function has been called, you have to call this function only once:

```
iCloudKV.sync(syncSuccess, syncError);

function syncSuccess(_dictionary){
    // You can retrieve into the _dictionary object datas saved in the cloud.
    // Example with datas I have saved:
    var playerID = _dictionary['playerID'];
    var deviceUUID = _dictionary['deviceUUID'];
}
```

You don't have to call this function again later, you only need to initialized it once at the beginning.
After the syncSuccess() function has been called and has returned "success" state, you can now save, get, and remove datas into this object like this:

```
 iCloudKV.save(_key, _val, saveSuccess);
 iCloudKV.load(_key, loadSuccess, loadError);
 iCloudKV.remove(_key, removeSuccess);
```

Voilà!

I think there is an important point to understand with this plugin. That was unclear for me at the beginning so let's discuss it:

When you save or remove a key from the **iCloudKV** object, you are not dealing with the real *iCloud* in real time. The *iCloudKV* object is a local object (if I'm wrong please let me know), which will be checked and analyzed by the real iOS syncing datas process. The iOS syncing process manage the **iCloudKV** object by itself, you can't directly ask to *iCloud* to save this or remove this. You only talk with the **iCloudKV** object.

For example when you save a key-value one your device1 using this plugin. This key-value is saved into the local **iCloudKV** object. You can't get it right after on the device2.

When you quit the app on device1, the iOS syncing data process will check your **iCloudKV** object, then if needed, will sync it on the real *iCloud* account online. If you launch your app now on the device2 (connected to the same *iCloud* account), the iOS syncing process will sync your datas, then the **iCloudKV** object will be able to return them to you.

By this way, you can't see changes between your device1 and your device2 in real time. First you have to wait the iOS syncing process does the job. I did lot of test before understanding this concept :)

I hope this will help somebody. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo. Should be `cloud` not `icloud`.

```
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"/>
```

Comment: You right, but actually I made a mistake when I wrote my example... During my "real test" I used "cloud" instead of "icloud"... I will correct that in my example right now! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to codesign the binary with correct entitlements file as well. Otherwise the iCloud service won't be available to your app. 
You can refer to [Adding Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) documentation on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will read the doc and try it! Do you know if I have to submit my app via Test Flight to do the test? Or can I simply install my app with Xcode on my iPhone and iPad and do the auto sync test?

Comment: What's the answer? :)

Comment: @redolent : You don't need TestFlight to make it works (luckily). Once the plugin is installed and once Xcode capabilities settings have been set, the key/value storage will be available between all iOS devices connected to the same iCloud account.